Image Not Rotating Correctly in Portrait Mode Using ImageAnalysis
I'm facing an issue with image rotation in my Android app while using the ImageAnalysis class from the CameraX library. The images captured in portrait mode are not being rotated correctly on a specific device (Huawei Nova 12 SE.) It works fine on other devices I tested (Pixel 7, Samsung Galaxy A55.)
Here is the relevant code:
fun <T, R> analyzeImageAsync(
        imageProxy: ImageProxy,
        onProcess: (input: InputImage) -> Task<T>,
        transform: (result: T) -> R?
    ): Deferred<R?> = scope.async {
        val image = InputImage.fromMediaImage(
             imageProxy.image ?: return@async null,
            imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
        )

        suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            onProcess(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    continuation.resume(transform(result))
                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    continuation.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
        }
    }

When I view the image captured, I see the image being rotated in 90 degrees, changing the rotation degrees to 0 doesn't change the result of the image.
I also tried to change the image to Bitmap, hoping it will fix the problem, but the result was the same:
fun <T, R> analyzeImageAsync(
    imageProxy: ImageProxy,
    onProcess: (input: InputImage) -> Task<T>,
    transform: (result: T) -> R?
): Deferred<R?> = scope.async {
    val bitmap = imageProxy.toBitmap() 
    val inputImage = InputImage.fromBitmap(bitmap, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees) 
    // Further processing...
}

Any help with this?
Edit:
The first image is what I expect the image to be like, the second one is the one I get, which is rotated.



I can't give you a detailed solution, but I faced a similar issue when I tried to get a bitmap image directly after launching the camera activity.  However, when I saved the image to a file first and then displayed it, the rotation issue did not occur. You could consider this approach. Hopefully it will help.

Unfortunately this is not efficient for my purpose since I'm using the image analyzer for scanning.
